# How to search for text in another sheet, incorporating length, and adjust hyperlink?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I'm trying to update hyperlinks in one Excel spreadsheet, using a Find in another sheet in the same workbook.

The problem occurs on `j = c.Find(k).Row`, where I receive the message

> "Runtime error '91:' Object variable or With block variable not set."

It doesn't give me any issues with the `d = c.Find(m).Row` which looks like it's been set up identically.
I know nothing about error handling in VBA - I've just never had to use it - so maybe there's something wrong with the result of the search?

```vb
Sub HypFix()

Dim k As String
Dim m As String
Dim i As Long
Dim g As String
Dim d As String
Dim j As String
Dim c As Range

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'CHANGE SHEET NAMES BELOW AS NEEDED

Set c = Sheets("Tables").Range("A1:A15071")
    
For i = 4 To 337
    If Sheets("Contents").Cells(i, "A").Value <> "" Then
        k = Sheets("Contents").Cells(i, "A").Value
        m = Right(Sheets("Contents").Cells(i, "A").Value, 255)
        g = Sheets("Contents").Cells(i, "A").Value
            If Len(Sheets("Contents").Cells(i, "A").Value) > 255 Then
                d = c.Find(m).Row
                Sheets("Contents").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("Contents").Cells(i, "A"), _
                Address:="", _
                SubAddress:="'Tables'!A" & d, _
                TextToDisplay:=g
            ElseIf Len(Sheets("Contents").Cells(i, "A").Value) <= 255 Then
                j = c.Find(k).Row
                Sheets("Contents").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("Contents").Cells(i, "A"), _
                Address:="", _
                SubAddress:="'Tables'!A" & j, _
                TextToDisplay:=g
            End If
    End If
Next i
    
'Message Box when tasks are completed
MsgBox "Task Complete!"

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.CalculateFull

End Sub
```

Comment: When using `Find`, you should always specify `What`, `LookIn`, and `LookAt`, and you should also [test if `Find` succeeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29066633/find-if-find-method-returns-nothing-in-excel-vba) before attempting `.Row`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that and let you know how that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always set a range to the `Range.Find()`.  This allows you to test whether a value was found without throwing an error.

```
Sub HypFix()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As Range
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim What As String
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'CHANGE SHEET NAMES BELOW AS NEEDED

    Set c = Sheets("Tables").Range("A1:A15071")
    With Sheets("Contents")
        For i = 4 To 337
            What = .Cells(i, "A").Value
            If Len(What) > 0 Then
 
                Set Target = c.Find(What:=What, LookIn:=xlValues)
                
                Rem Test if anything was found
                If Not Target Is Nothing Then
                    Rem Look for the Last 255 characters
                    Set Target = c.Find(What:=Right(What, 255), LookIn:=xlValues)
                End If
    
                
                Rem If something was found link it
                If Not Target Is Nothing Then
                    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(i, "A"), Address:="", SubAddress:="'Tables'!A" & Target.Row
                Else
                    Rem Leave yourself a message of what wasn't found
                    Debug.Print What, " in row "; i; "Not Found"
                End If

            End If
        Next i
    End With
    'Message Box when tasks are completed
    MsgBox "Task Complete!"

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.CalculateFull

End Sub
```

Note: When the `TextToDisplay` parameter is omitted from `.Hyperlinks.Add` the Anchor cell's test is displayed.

Comment: Elegant and worked beautifully - thank you!  I've read some of your other answers over the years and they've been very useful.  Thank you for your help here and for all your contributions to the community!

Comment: @EZarrella Thanks!  It's my pleasure.